# Does Rascal do tail-call optimization?

Tags: rascal

Does Rascal do tail-call optimization?  In particular, if I write code using tail recursion instead of those built-in loop construct, do I expect efficiency penalty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should expect efficiency penalty with the current implementation.

We do expect the compiler (which is being written now) to do tail-call optimization in the future.

Comment: Cool!  Looking forward to that.

Comment: Moreover, since there is a little bit of a call overhead, and the our immutable values, comprehensions are the fastest way to construct values. (currently!)

Comment: A "little bit" of call overhead... ;-)